# Memory leak using scipy.eigs

Tags: python, memory-leaks, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I have a set of large very sparse matrices which I'm trying to find the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 0 of. From the structure of the underlying problem I know a solution to this must exist and that zero is also the largest eigenvalue.

To solve the problem I use `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` with arguments:

```
val, rho = eigs(L, k=1, which = 'LM', v0=init, sigma=-0.001)
```

where `L` is the matrix. I then call this multiple times for different matrices. At first I was having a severe problem where the memory usage just increases as I call the function more and more times. It seems `eigs` doesn't free all the memory it should. I solved by calling `gc.collect()` each time I use `eigs`.

But now I worry that also internally memory isn't being freed, naively I expect that using something like Arnoldi shouldn't use more memory as the algorithm progresses, it should just be storing the matrix and the current set of Lanczos vectors, but I find that memory usage increases while the code is still inside the `eigs` function.

Any ideas?